# Java to Binary cross compilation

Tags: java, binary, exe

as you know you can compile C code to binary. Is there a way in which I can convert a java command line program to binary??

I need it because I made an interpreter in Java and I need to add it to the path of the users PC such that the user does not need to install java or JVM on his or her machine

Comment: Well, there are tools to create exe files from jars but why would you want to do so? Why not provide an installer that adds the JVM as well? It's not that uncommon a thing to do.

Comment: That page is old, try JPackage [https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html]